# OAuthException: (#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

i am stuck on this error when i post event to my wall through offline posting
`OAuthException: (#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher`

Comment: What do you mean with posting event to your wall?

Creating and editing events are not available in API v2.0

Comment: when i am going to create the event the above error is occurred ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create events anymore with the Graph API v2.0:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/#publish
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Quote:

> the `create_event` permission is no longer available.

Comment: create event is not available in graph api. but created in this formate
$facebook_event = $facebook->api("/200356593506038/events", "POST", $data);

Comment: Have you read the first link? `You cannot create events via the Graph API.` This is no longer possible! That's why you get the error

Comment: yes i read this link. i use the code that i post above and created the event but when i use java-script to connect with Facebook and the
( OAuthException: (#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher)
error occured

Comment: i am sitll having this issue `OAuthException: (#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher`