# Is there any possible way to create facebook page event through JS SDK or Graph API on version 3.1?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create facebook page event through Graph API or JS SDK but I got error message that "error": { message: "(#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher", type: "OAuthException", code: 12, fbtrace_id: "GcLkGbEV6zP"} .

I have read through documentation and across google search, they say the same way that facebook doesn’t support to that function since version2.0.

But, I have used an application which is providing facebook page event creating through their system few days ago. Therefore, I am just wondering is there any possible way or permission to be able to create facebook page event through my system by using Graph API or JavaScript SDK?

Please help me!

Comment: no, there is no possibility. that other tool may have a special deal with facebook, one you will most likely not get.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @luschn, I got it clearly.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798306/oauthexception-12-events-management-api-is-deprecated-for-versions-v2-0-and