# Create event from the facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to the FB graph API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/#Creating

> ### Creating
>
> ### Permissions
>
> - An access token of an Admin of the Event if required.
>
> You can make a POST request to live_videos edge from the following paths:
>
> - /{event_id}/live_videos
>
> When posting to this edge, an Event will be created.

However this is ambiguous - it seems like its referring to live videos, not creating an event itself.

So my question is, in 2018 after all the Cambridge Analytica API shutdowns and permissions changes, how do I programatically create a Facebook event in Javascript having access to the admin page token?

Thanks

Comment: It has not been possible to create events using the API for many many years. Long before Cambridge Analytica.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting /me/events, I get this return:
(#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher"

Similar post here: [OAuthException: (#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798306/oauthexception-12-events-management-api-is-deprecated-for-versions-v2-0-and)

Live videos can be created on existing events (as you have pointed out). But not the ability to create/manage events.